# How import a 3D numpy array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Using python 3, I am trying to process a set of data in a four-column text file: The first column is the *x* index, the second column is the *y* index and the third column is the *z* index, or depth index. The fourth column is the data value. The values in the text file look like this:

```
0 0 0 0.0
1 0 0 0.0
2 0 0 2.0
0 1 0 0.0
1 1 0 0.0
2 1 0 2.0
0 2 0 0.0
1 2 0 0.0
2 2 0 2.0
0 0 1 0.0
1 0 1 0.0
2 0 1 2.0
0 1 1 0.0
1 1 1 0.0
2 1 1 2.0
0 2 1 0.0
1 2 1 0.0
2 2 1 2.0
```

Is there a way to construct a 3D numpy array with shape (2,3,3)?

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [2 2 2]],
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [2 2 2]]]
```

While this example shows 18 rows wanting to be shaped into a (2,3,3) array, my actual data is 512x512x49 (12845056) rows and I'd like to shape them into a (512,512,49) array. If the solution could efficiently parse a greater number of rows, that would be appreciated, but I understand python has some fundamental speed limitations.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
f = "file_path.txt"
data = np.loadtxt(f)
data = data.reshape((512,512,49))
```

but this gives the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 51380224 into shape (512,512,49)
```

I was surprised by this error since 51380224 is not equal to the number of rows in my loaded array (12845056). Also, I suspect numpy needs information that the first, second, and third columns are not values, but indices along which to shape the values in the fourth column. I am not sure how to achieve this, and am open to solutions in either `numpy` or `pandas`.

Comment: somehow you've loaded 4x as many elements as expected.  Check `data.shape` and `data.dtype`.  How about a reshape to (512,512,49,4)?

Comment: `data.shape` returns `(12845056, 4)` and `data.dtype` returns `dtype('float64')`. The 4x number of rows may be due to `numpy` incorrectly interpreting my four-column data set. `data.reshape(512,512,49,4)` returns an array with shape (512,512,49,4), but I still don't think the data are in the proper structure; I accessed the first ''depth'' of the `data.reshape(512,512,49,4)` using `data[:,:,0,0]`, but it does not look correct.

Comment: If the file has 128... rows and 4 columns, then numpy has properly loaded it. The interpretation of those columns is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your sample file:

```
In [94]: txt = """0 0 0 0.0
    ...: 1 0 0 0.0
    ...: 2 0 0 2.0
    ...: 0 1 0 0.0
    ...: 1 1 0 0.0
    ...: 2 1 0 2.0
    ...: 0 2 0 0.0
    ...: 1 2 0 0.0
    ...: 2 2 0 2.0
    ...: 0 0 1 0.0
    ...: 1 0 1 0.0
    ...: 2 0 1 2.0
    ...: 0 1 1 0.0
    ...: 1 1 1 0.0
    ...: 2 1 1 2.0
    ...: 0 2 1 0.0
    ...: 1 2 1 0.0
    ...: 2 2 1 2.0""".splitlines()
```

The straight forward load detects 4 columns, and makes all values float:

```
In [95]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt)
In [96]: data.shape
Out[96]: (18, 4)
```

We could work from those, converting the float indices to integer.  Or we can load the file in 2 steps:

```
In [103]: indices = np.genfromtxt(txt, usecols=[0,1,2], dtype=int)
In [104]: values = np.genfromtxt(txt, usecols=[3])
```

and use those values to fill in an array:

```
In [105]: res = np.zeros((2,3,3),float)
In [107]: res[indices[:,2],indices[:,0],indices[:,1]] = values
In [108]: res
Out[108]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [2., 2., 2.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [2., 2., 2.]]])
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!! Since I am loading my data using `np.loadtxt`, I extended your solution to my dataset by replacing your `indices` and `values` lines with: `indices = data[:,0:3].astype('int')`, `values = data[:,3]`, and `res = np.zeros(49,512,512)`. These variables produce the structure I am looking for, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Numpy itself does not have any special function for such case, but the solution is easy.
From the step where you get input to the `data` all you need to do is to use first, second and third columns as indexes.
*Warning*: while the cartesian coordinates are notated as (x,y,z), arrays are represented in an inverse way: first dimension is z, second is y and third is x `data[z,y,x]`.
With that in mind you can use the columns in `data` as indexes:

```
# Assuming the first dimension are rows in data
x, y, z = data[:,0:3].astype(np.int32).T  # we first need to get indexes as integers 
extracted_data = np.zeros((512,512,49))  # creating array of a desired size
extracted_data[z, y, x] = data[:,3]  # filling it with data
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer attempt. Unfortunately, I get the following error after the very first line you gave: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`. I think this has to do with trying to set three variables, `xyz` , equal to a structure with two columns, `data[:,0:3]`. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @TWalker fixed the answer, should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Though I selected @hpaulj answer as the solution, here is a full working example for clarity:

```
import numpy as np
f = "file_path.txt"
data = np.loadtxt(f)
indices = data[:,0:3].copy().astype('int')
values = data[:,3].copy()
res = np.zeros((49,512,512),float)
res[indices[:,2],indices[:,0],indices[:,1]] = values
```